# jQuery request does not allow me to access returned JSON value?

Tags: jquery

How can I access this variable returned from an AJAX request with jQuery?

```
.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
    console.log(response);
})
```

`response` returns this `{"msg":"ERROR: Record Not Saved"}`

Now when I try to access `response.msg` It prints out `undefined`

How can I access response.msg ?

Comment: Is your server returning the proper JSON content type? Are you using `dataType: "json"`?

Comment: @Jon My AJAX is a `type: "POST"` to the server,  The server then returns JSON using `echo json_encode($arr);`

Comment: I take it that means no and no?

Comment: Either do `header("Content-Type: application/json");` on server or set `dataType: "json"` param from client. Or, third option, parse response with `JSON.parse(repsonse)`

Comment: @Tommi setting `header("Content-Type: application/json");` made everything work perfectly...I haven't working with AJAX in a long time, completely forgot about this thanks a bunch.  If you would like to post this as answer I can select it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first echo `response.msg` on the server-side as a JSON string:

```php
$hi_msg = array('msg'=>'hi there!');
echo json_encode($hi_msg);
```

Then you can access `response.msg` on the client-side via jQuery.